# How can I toast rice without using an oven?

Tags: rice

Rice can be toasted for adding more taste and flavor. The recipe I have uses an oven to toast rice. I want to find out another method which toasts rice without using an oven.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put it in a dry frying pan on medium high heat and stir frequently until perfectly toasted.

Comment: Note that you need to watch it closely cause it's easier to burn the rice than in an oven.

Comment: It helps to use a drop of oil in the pan and constant shaking to prevent burning. ( similarv to the old way of popping corn)

Comment: ..Preferably a nice sauté pan, with a curved profile to the sides.. toss occasionally while coming up to heat, and continuously when the color starts to change. Have a  cool place ready to tip the rice out onto, reasonably well spread out, as soon as you reach the point you want it to get to.

Comment: Like a cookie sheet to spread the rice onto.